# Unable to upload random file to RESTFUL web service

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating some kind of File Manager for company product, and I'm having this method where I post files. But for some files, e.g. .jpg its working, for some it's not.

Problem is not with handling uploaded file, my method for upload is not even executing for those files, I have tried many solution, googled, and nothing works. I believe that its related to validation but I have also tried to remove validation for all methods and still it doesn't work.

This is my method

```
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{courseName}")]
        public Stream UploadFile(string courseName)
        {

            var _files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
            string path = String.Format(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Resources\{0}\{1}\", courseName, "{0}");
            List<Finfo> li = FileManagerHelper.UploadFile(courseName, path, _files);

            MessageTypes.Instance.SetJsonMessage();
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(li).StringToStream();

        }
```

don't bother with the custom methods and custom objects, problem is that this method is not even called.

Thanks in advance who ever answers, and any solution is welcome.

Comment: Have you checked the MIME types on the server?

Comment: Is there any difference between the files which successfully upload and those which don't?  For example, are the files which fail to upload larger than those which upload successfully?

Comment: First Comment: Already uploading image/jpeg files,

Comment: Second comment: They are all around 100Kb so its not request limit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother to test, solution found on microsoft site, that is BUG and can be solved only upgrading to WCF 4.5, cause in version 4.0 max size is 65KB

Thanks Microsoft, I have lost two days of my life trying to solve it.